# Multiple SSL Certificates on Elastic Beanstalk ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

Is it possible to link more than 1 SSL certificate to an Elastic Beanstalk ALB?

I understand that one can create a bundle domain certificate in Certificate Manager, but I would ultimately want to give my clients the ability to add their own domain pointers pointing to the EB environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Probably not from EB console, but you can deploy multiple SSL certs on ALB as explained in:

- [Application Load Balancers Now Support Multiple TLS Certificates With Smart Selection Using SNI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-sni/)

You would have to go to EC2 console -> Load balancers, and work with the ALB there. Obviously you could do the same things using AWS CLI or SDK if you want to automate things.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, turned out to be super easy. On EC2 > LB > Listeners Tab > Go to your 443 port (if you don't have this you need to first add a Listener on EB under config) > Click on View/Edit certificates > Click on the + > Choose another certificate from your Certificate Manager. Brilliant AWS!

Comment: @AntonSwanevelder Glad it worked out:-)